# Position textarea at bottom of div and fill to (width - 2px margins)

Tags: css

I thought we were mostly past this sort of thing, but I've discovered an inconsistency (presumably well-known to all you CSS demi-gods out there) in how Firefox and IE display something vs. Chrome.

Take a look at this jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/smithkl42/jmgEV/1/

```
div.parent{
  position:relative;
  height:200px;
  width:400px;
  background-color:blue;
}

textarea.child{
  position:absolute;
  height:30px;
  bottom:2px;
  left:2px;
  right:2px;
}
```

In Chrome it does what I want it to, namely, to display the `<textarea>` at the bottom of its parent div, and be as wide as the parent div. But in FireFox and IE, it ignores the `right:2px` line, and just gives it the default width.

If I replace the `<textarea>` with a `<div>` (see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/smithkl42/jmgEV/2/), it behaves the way I want.

Any idea why?

EDIT: 
Thanks for all the suggestions. I should note that the parent element (in the real world, not in my fiddle) is gonna be changing size, so I can't use any of the suggestions that say, "Just set the width manually". For instance, I need it to be *exactly* two pixels from the left and right edges whether its parent element is 1200 pixels wide or 50. So things like setting it to a %, which would work it if was mostly fixed-width, won't work here. For other comments, see below.

Comment: I'm not sure of the technical reasons. I actually put together a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thirdender/ULHbs/) a while back illustrating how some elements respond to being absolute positioned. `IFRAME`, `TABLE`, `SELECT`, and `TEXTAREA` elements don't behave the same as other elements. The best solution I found was to add a `DIV` around the element, give that `DIV` the desired dimensions, then make the problem element `width: 100%; height: 100%;`: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thirdender/9TTJ6/)

Comment: just give width in % for child textarea.. (for eg 100% or 96% )

Comment: @thirdender - Yeah, this is the only solution I've found. Still really darned odd that it works differently in FF vs. Chrome. I thought they'd worked all those bugs out of the CSS spec by now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always define **width** to the [replaced](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/replacedelements) element with `position:absolute`. `<textarea>` is an replaced element. Write like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        <textarea></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.parent{
    position:relative;
    height:200px;
    width:400px;
    background-color:blue;
}

.child{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:2px;
    left:2px;
    right:2px;
}
.child textarea{
    width:100%;
    height:30px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/jmgEV/10/

Comment: if you set it 100% it will overline

Comment: @Sugar check the fiddle example

Comment: hm... `box-sizing` looks like cheater :D

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know the exact width at design-time (as the parent will be changing size), and I need it to be a defined number of pixels from its parent's left and right edges. So using a % doesn't work.

Comment: it's work that's why i define textarea inside div. Check the jsfiddle example it's work for you.

Comment: Good point, sorry, missed that. Accepting as answer :-). Any idea why Chrome and FF handle this differently? (I'm assuming understanding why IE does anything is a lost cause.)

Comment: BTW, +1 for the box-sizing tip.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's wrong implementation of IE - he can't to scretch it.Dat IE. I think more easier way to fix it - set `mwidth` to `.child` too. Or set `min-width`

```
.child{
     position:absolute;
     height:30px;
     bottom:2px;
     right:2px;
     left:2px;
     min-width:394px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.parent{
position:relative;
height:200px;
width:400px;
background-color:blue;
}

.child{
position:absolute;
height:30px;
bottom:2px;
left:2px;
right:2px;
}

<div class="parent">
<textarea class="child" cols="47" style=" resize: none;"></textarea>
</div>
```

Hi,
I hope this will help you. 
Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/jmgEV/8/

Thank you.

Comment: In my real-world page, the parent element is going to be changing size dynamically, based on a whole bunch of factors - so I can't use the `cols=xx` trick, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Try this .child{ position:absolute; width:97%; height:30px; bottom:2px; left:2px; right:2px; }

Answer (score 0):

The `textarea` is an `inline` elementand the `div` element is a `block` element.

In your working example, the `.child` is a `div` (a `block` element) so it is stretch horizontally to fit its parent witdh.

In yout no-working example, the `child` is a `textarea` (an `inline` element) so it will not stretch automatically.

Another reason is the default width of the `textarea` element. This element has a attribute called `cols`, which decides how long the `textarea` is, calculated in character. This attributes has a default value of `20`, so if do not specify the value for the `width` property, your `textarea` will apply this default value.

**Compare to an inline element without `width` specified**
With other inline element like `span` or `q`, if the `width` property is not set, it will have the width equal to zero.

Comment: Because unlike other block element like `div` or `p`, the `textarea` have a default `width` which equals to 20 character - see the default values of the `cols` attributes. So if you do not specified the `width`, it will apply this default values.